# Simple Linked List C code Segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am making a linked list program for my basic C assignment. 
However, I will always get the force closed error on .exe and get a segmentation fault on Ubuntu.

I tried to break it down and rewrite but I have no idea where the code fails.

I'd appreciate your help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


    struct node{
            char name[20];
            int mark;
            struct node *next;

    };

    struct node *addnode(char name[], float mark);


    int main(void){

            int j = 0;
            char StdName[10];
            float StdMarks;

            struct node *head = NULL;
            struct node *curr = NULL;

            head = curr = addnode('\0',0.0);

            for(j=0; j<3; j++){

                    printf("\nEnter StdName >>");

                    printf("\nMarks for %s >>", StdName);


                    curr -> next = addnode("", 5.5);
                    curr = curr->next;
            }

            curr = head -> next;

            j = 0;

            printf("\nnode\tName\tMarks");

            while(curr){

                    printf("\n%d\t%s\t%5.2f", j++, curr->name, curr->mark);
                    curr=curr->next;
            }

    return 0;

    }

    struct node *addnode(char name[], float mark){

            struct node *temp;

            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            strcpy(temp->name,name);
            temp->mark=mark;
            temp->next=NULL;

    return (temp);
    }
```

Comment: Considered using a debugger? Try looking for `gdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few mistakes:

- `'\0'` is not a `char[]`, but a `char` whose value is `0` and converted to a `char*` (`NULL` pointer). Use `""` for an empty string. The compiler should have emitted a warning for this. Compile with warning level at highest and treat warnings as errors (so you cannot ignore them). For `gcc` the flags are `-Wall -Werror`.
- `StdName` is not initialised and is never populated but is used in a `printf("%s")` call.

Comment: @AminHusni if this answers your question you should accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The first node you add you use a single char `'\0'` for name, when you should pass a string:

```
head = curr = addnode("", 0.0);
```

And also this doesn't point to the first node, it points to the second one:

```
curr = head -> next;
```

Should be:

```
curr = head;
```

I don't know what you intended to do with `StdName` but as hmjd said, it should be initialized to some value.

```
char StdName[] ="stdname";
```

Comment: Alright, the code worked. It's the 

head = curr = addnode("", 0.0); problem.



Thanks :) http://pastebin.com/6GreaqTv

Answer (score 0):

`head = curr = addnode('\0',0.0);` line is invalid. Your `addnode` function expects a pointer to characters array as first parameter. `'\0'` is an integer value equal to 0. You pass the `name` to `strcpy` which uses it as a pointer to source data. Since the pointer is 0 (== NULL), you get a crash.